# Prove that for each natural number n, any set with n elements has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ two-element subsets

Tags: natural-numbers

Prove that for each natural number n, any set with n elements has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ two-element subsets.

I'm just confused by what this is asking, I haven't learned about two-element subsets yet.

Comment: One way to think about this. If there are $n$ people in a room and everyone shakes hands with everyone else, how many handshakes are there?

Comment: This can be handled with one of the famous [proofs without words](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8847/15503). That visualization is really about the identity that the number of two element subsets is equal to the sum $1+2+\cdots+(n-1)$. So to make use of that proof you either need to know the sum formula of an arithmetic progression or the binomial coefficient $\binom n2$. Not sure that this is optimal for the current asker, but it does visualize a connection everybody should see at least once :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some answers don't seem to be addressing the OP's concern that they don't understand what the question is asking, rather than not knowing how to proceed with the question.

The idea of the terms in the question are as follows: In mathematics, we call a collection of objects a **set**. You can have sets of very concrete objects, like the set of things on a table, or very mathy ones, like the set of integers between $0$ and $7$ inclusive. We would write the last one $$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$$
The curly brackets indicate that we have a set of the objects inside. Now, a **subset** A of a set $B$ is a set so that every member of $A$ is also a member of $B$. What this means is that $A$ and $B$ are collections of objects and $B$ contains every object that $A$ contains, and possibly more. A **two element** subset is a subset that has two things in it.  If we let $B$ be the set of integers between $0$ and $7$ inclusive above, then $ \{1,2,3\}$ is a subset but not a two element subset, and $\{4,6\}$ is both a subset and has two elements, hence it is a two element subset.

So, your question is asking that if you start with a set $S$ that has $n$ things in it, how many two element subsets of $S$ are there? You can do some small examples yourself explicitly. For instance if $S$ has 1 element, then it has no two element subsets, and if $S$ has 2 elements, then $S$ has exactly one two element subset: $S$ itself. Now suppose $S$ has three elements, say $S=\{1,2,3\}$ can you list all the 2 element subsets? What about larger $n$?

Comment: okay this makes sense, thanks for describing it so well. the 2 element subsets could be {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}

Comment: @Claire You got it. So there are three in total. Now, you want to try and solve the problem for $n$ without picking a particular value for it. So start with a set $S$ that we are going to assume has $n$ elements. How can we make a 2-element subset of $S$? Well, you can start by picking one element of $S$, and then pick another element (which must be different than the first element!) Your goal is to count the number of ways of doing this.

Comment: So since this claim must be true for all natural numbers, when $n=1$, the set $S$ has only one element, no 2-element subsets. Can you make a 2-element subset of S by considering $n+1$ in the subset since we supposed that $n$ was in the subset?

Comment: @Claire Well, you're trying to show that the claim is true for all natural numbers. Currently, we have shown it for $n=1,2,3$. Your last sentence makes me think you are trying to use mathematical induction. Do you know what this is?

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that I have to prove the claim is true by using mathematical induction because this homework assignment is based on our current unit on induction proofs. We just haven't learned about induction proofs that involve subsets, just divisibility, exponents, and factorials.

Comment: @Claire Induction is a very flexible tool. I know it can be hard to get used to new ways of using it. So our induction hypothesis says that any set of size $n$ has $n(n-1)/2$  two-element subsets. Pick a set of size $n+1$. If you pick out one element, say $a$ from your set, then you have $n$ many left. So, our induction hypothesis says that there are $n(n-1)/2$ many $2$-element subsets of our big set that do **not** contain $a$. Can you explicitly count the ones that do contain $a$ and then add those numbers together?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84442/discussion-between-claire-and-james).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that for the first element we can consider $(n-1)$ subsets: $$\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\ldots,\{1,n\}$$

for the second element we can consider $(n-2)$ subsets: $$\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\ldots,\{2,n\}$$

and so on.

Comment: where are these "objects" coming from? i'm just confused by the whole question because I haven't learned about any of this, and the textbook doesn't really cover it

Comment: @Claire object stands for element, I fix that

Comment: @Claire Given $n$ elements $1,2,...,n$ a two-element subsets is any "pair" $\{a,b\}$ with $a\neq b$ and $a,b \in \{1,2,...,n\}$. The question here is how to count those subsets.

Comment: okay that makes sense @gimusi

Comment: @Claire Well done! Bye

Comment: wait so how does that help in understanding the claim above??

Comment: i don't understand where the (n-2) comes from

Comment: @Claire A simple way to count them is start from the first one, with that we can create $n-1$ pairs. Then consider the second one, with that we can create $n-2$ pairs. Note that in the second step we do not consider (2,1) since we have already counted that subset as (1,2) in the first step. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

For your first element you have $n$ choices and for each choice you have $n-1$ choices for the second one.

That makes $n(n-1) $choices but since order does not matter the actual number of subsets are $n(n-1)/2$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a set with $n$ elements.

We can map ordered pairs from the Cartesian product $S \times S$ into subsets of $S$ as follows:

$\tag 1 (x,y) \mapsto \{x.y\} \text{ for every } x,y \in S$

The output of this function is a subset of $S$ with either one element or two elements.

With $a \ne b$, we get a subset with two elements,

$\quad (a,b) \mapsto \{a.b\}$

But we get the same subset when we switch the coordinates:

$\quad (b,a) \mapsto \{b.a\}$

So the mapping is $2:1$ when it is 'hitting' two element subsets. If $t$ is the number of subsets with two elements, this happens two times $t$.

We get a subset with one element like this:

$\quad (d,d) \mapsto \{d.d\}  = \{d\}$

Here it is $1:1$, one ordered pair 'on the diagonal' for each singleton subset of $S$; this happens exactly $n$ times.

Now we know that the set $S \times S$ has $n^2$ elements. But the above analysis allows us to also count up these elements as follows:

$\tag 2 n^2 = 2 t + n \text{, where } t \text{ is the number of subsets of } S \text{ containing exactly } 2 \text{ elements}$

Solving we get

$\tag 3 t = \frac{n^2 -n}{2}$